# What is a cleaner way to alternate colors in a foreach loop in PHP and when would processing speed really be a factor?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, alternate

Although this works, speed and cleanliness matter.

```
if (file_exists($fileToCheck)) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($fileToCheck);
    $lines = array_reverse(explode("\n", trim($contents))); 
    $line ="";
    $c = 0;
    foreach($lines as $row) {
        if ($c == 0) { $line .= "<span style='color:red;font-size:10px;'>".$row."</span><br>"; $c = +2; }
        if ($c == 1) { $line .= "<span style='color:blue;font-size:10px;'>".$row."</span><br>"; $c = +2; }
        if ($c == 2) { $c = 1; }
        if ($c == 3) { $c = 0; }
    }
} else { $line = "Huzzah! No errors today!"; }
```

Thanks.

Comment: yeah, use a modulo on `color:red;` ie. `$key % 1 ? 'red': 'blue'`

Comment: **Opinion based**. You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

Comment: In-line styles are frowned upon.  Use classes.  Or if these are paragraphs/table rows you could use CSS. `tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the modulus/modulo operator.

So, if you wanted to make all even numbers red, and the others blue, you would do this:

```
foreach($lines as $row) {
    if ($c % 2 == 0) { 
        $line .= "<span style='color:red;font-size:10px;'>".$row."</span><br>"; 
    } else {
        $line .= "<span style='color:blue;font-size:10px;'>".$row."</span><br>"; 
    }
    $c++;
}
```

You could simplify this further:

```
foreach($lines as $row) {
    $colour = ($c % 2 == 0) ? 'red' : 'blue';
    $line .= "<span style='color:".$colour.";font-size:10px;'>".$row."</span><br>"; 
    $c++;
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: @Progrock Thanks, just fixed that.

Comment: `$colour = ($c++ % 2 == 0) ? 'red' : 'blue';` and get rid of the last line in the loop...

Comment: `$line .= "<span style='color:".(($c++ % 2 == 0) ? 'red' : 'blue').";font-size:10px;'>".$row."</span><br>"; ` and make it a one-line loop

Comment: @mikeb Whilst I agree with you, I'd argue that that is less readable for a beginner imo.

Comment: @CountKyle I liked your simplified version. I do like mikeb's addition best. Thank you for the quick responses.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Same idea just less code

```
if (file_exists($fileToCheck)) {
$contents = file_get_contents($fileToCheck);
$lines = array_reverse(explode("\n", trim($contents)));
$line = "";
$c = 0;
foreach ($lines as $row) {
    $color = 'red';
    if ($c == 1) {
        $color = 'blue';
        $c = 0;
    } else {
        $c++;
    }
    $line .= "<span style='color:{$color};font-size:10px;'>" . $row . "</span><br>";
}
} else {
    $line = "Huzzah! No errors today!";
}
```

Comment: Effective, less code is always better.